# jbpm with liferay

Tags: liferay-6, jbpm

I can run a sample workflow done with jbpm5  ​​outside of liferay

but now I want to run this example in liferay

So the problem is how to integrate jbpm5 with liferay

I think I need to edit some configuration files in liferay

I'm reading these [instructions](http://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/1071674/How+to+Set+Up+JBPM+with+Liferay) but I can not find the solution

Answer (score 0):

It's not than simple if you are trying to integrate jBPM5. As you can see the tutorial that you mention has being written for jbpm 3.1.2, a very old version. It will be a great community contribution to integrate jBPM5 to liferay, so if you are interested we can guide you, but you will need to do the work and research to get it working. I can help you with the jBPM5 but you will need to dig into the liferay bits.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest if you want to run Workflow inside Liferay, first you must find a plugin for workflow engine. As fas as I know, Liferay supports Activity, JBPM, Kaleo,.. Have you downloaded JBPM plugin for Liferay? Because for default Liferay using Kaleo.